# Using strtok/strtok_r in a while loop in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, tokenize, strtok

I'm getting unexpected behavior from the strtok and strtrok_r functions:

```
queue<string> tks;
char line[1024];
char *savePtr = 0;

while(true)
{
    //get input from user store in line

    tks.push(strtok_r(line, " \n", &savePtr));  //initial push only works right during first loop

    char *p = nullptr;
    for (...)
    {
        p = strtok_r(NULL, " \n", &savePtr);
        if (p == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        tks.push(p);
    }
    delete p;
    savePtr = NULL;

    //do stuff, clear out tks before looping again

}
```

I've tried using `strtok` and realized that during the second loop, the initial push is not occurring.  I attempted to use the reentrant version `strtok_r` in order to control what the saved pointer is pointing to during the second loop by making sure it is null before looping again.

`tks` is only correctly populated during the first time through the loop - subsequent loops give varying results depending on the length of `line`

What am I missing here?

Comment: [mcve] or it didn't happen.

Comment: Important fun fact: strtok (and strtok_r) doesn't `new` the  pointer is assigns to `p`. It takes the string you put in, `line` and chops it up, inserting a null character in place of the next found of the delimiters and then returns a pointer to the first character of the now-null-terminated string. So `delete p;` is actually trying to `delete` part of `line`. Ka-boom. OK. Maybe not, because what you're really deleting is NULL because of the loop exit condition. Probably shouldn't do that anyway, though.

Comment: Gotcha... this doesn't affect my problem though :(

Comment: Suggestion: since you already know you have a line from the user, the `\n`  delimiter seems kind of redundant. You can put `line` into a `std::stringstream linestream(line);`, then `std::getline(linestream, word, ' ');` where `word` is `std::string`, and then `tks.push(word);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just focusing on the inner loop and chopping off all of the stuff I don't see as necessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::queue<std::string> tks;

    while(true)
    {
        char line[1024];
        char *savePtr;
        char *p;
        cin.getline(line, sizeof(line));
        p = strtok_r(line, " \n", &savePtr); // initial read. contents of savePtr ignored
        while (p != NULL) // exit when no more data, which includes an emtpy line
        {
            tks.push(p); // got data, store it
            p = strtok_r(NULL, " \n", &savePtr); // get next token
        }
        // consume tks  
    }
}
```

I prefer the while loop over the for loop used by Toby Speight in his answer because I think it is more transparent and easier to read. Your mileage may vary. By the time the compiler is done with it they will be identical.

There is no need to delete any memory. It is all statically allocated. There is no need to clear anything before the next round except for `tks`. `savePtr` will be reset by the first `strtok_r`.

There is a failure case if the user inputs more than 1024  characters on a line, but this will not crash. If this still doesn't work, look into how you're consuming `tks`. It's not posted so we can't troubleshoot that portion.

Wholeheartedly recommend changing to a string-based solution if possible. This is a really simple, easy to write, but slow, one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::queue<std::string> tks;

    while(true)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::stringstream linestream(line);
        std::string word;
        // parse only on  ' ', not on the usual all whitespace of >>
        while (std::getline(linestream, word, ' ')) 
        {
            tks.push(word);
        }
        // consume tks  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code wouldn't compile for me, so I fixed it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

std::queue<std::string> tks;

int main() {
    char line[1024] = "one \ntwo \nthree\n";
    char *savePtr = 0;

    for (char *p = strtok_r(line, " \n", &savePtr);  p;
                          p = strtok_r(nullptr, " \n", &savePtr))
        tks.push(p);

    // Did we read it correctly?
    for (;  tks.size() > 0;  tks.pop())
        std::cout << ">" << tks.front() << "<" << std::endl;
}
```

This produces the expected output:

```
>one<
>two<
>three<
```

So your problem isn't with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to use boost, try this one out to tokenize a string. Of course by providing your own string and delimeters.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Any\nString\nYou want";

    std::vector< std::string > results;
    boost::split( results, str, boost::is_any_of( "\n" ) );
}
```